# Splitting up module functionality into separate files

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-module

I'm new to modules and want to split up a lengthy .psm1 file into multiple files for maintainability.  What is the best way to do this?

I've got it working using dot sourcing but I suspect there is a better way of creating a module with multiple files.

Currently my file structure is:

```
Logger/ (module directory)
|
-- Logger.psd1 (module manifest)
|
-- Logger.psm1 (main functions exported from module)
|
-- Configuration.ps1 (configuration-related functions, exported from module)
|
-- Private/ (directory)
    |
    -- SharedFunctions.ps1 (functions called by Logger.psm1 and 
    |                       Configuration.ps1, not exported)
    |
    -- ModuleState.ps1 (variables that record the module configuration, 
                        used by all other script files)
```

I've got this working by chaining the files together using dot sourcing:

- In Logger.psm1 I've added `. $PSScriptRoot\Configuration.ps1` to include the functions from the Configuration.ps1 file;
- In Configuration.ps1 I've added `. $PSScriptRoot\Private\SharedFunctions.ps1` to include the functions from Private\SharedFunctions.ps1;
- In SharedFunctions.ps1 I've added `. $PSScriptRoot\ModuleState.ps1` to include the variables in ModuleState.ps1 which record the module configuration.

This works but seems brittle and messy.  Is there a better way to split files within a module, perhaps using the  manifest file?